# Android: How to make TableRow height and ImageView height to be equal to ImageView scr drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem to make TableRow and ImageView height to be equal to ImageView scr drawable height.

Could somebody helps me to fix this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:gravity="top" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView android:text="Some text" 
                android:id="@+id/textView1" android:gravity="top" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:gravity="top|center" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/burger_king_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: setting android:layout_height to "wrap_content" should do that for you. Can you post a picture of what the View looks like with this xml code? It wouldn't hurt if you could elaborate on what you are trying to get it to come out looking like either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, however it looks like ImageView has an option setAdjustViewBounds that may do everything you need:

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

If this is not enough, you can get the drawable's height with something like this:

```
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.burger_king_image);
    int height = image.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

Then you can set the size of your ImageView like so (assuming the content view has already been set to this resource):

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setMaxHeight(height);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Hope this helps.